# JQuery plugin to do this effect?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there a JQuery plugin that does this effect which is on this page?

http://www.aspslideshow.com/Samples/AmazonMusic/tabid/87/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the bouncy-drop-in, it looks to me like (roughly) a
`.show("drop", { direction: "down" }, 300);`
followed by a
`.effect("bounce", { times:2 }, 200);`

There's a bit more to it than just that, as the bounce accelerates like a physics object and the height degrades, and the transparency appears to be based on the height of the object, but that's essentially it.

If you want more control over things like that, you'd probably be better off with [Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/).  It has more control for effects than jQuery has (or appears to have, I'm not jQuery-fluent), and you can almost definitely hack something nearly identical together with tweening and parallel effects.
There may also be a plugin for jQuery to do this, though I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty similar to this: http://demo.hotjoomlatemplates.com/test/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=57

It uses jQuery tabs + auto rotate. Just check it's code / script.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure which one you are talking about, try and be more specific with your question. For the bouncy text I would use the ease plugin for its easeoutbounce function. For the pictures you could use a simple innerfade.